# MEAN.js - How to hide data based on Role

Tags: meanjs

I am looking for a way to hide elements from certain user based on his roles in MEAN.js

e.g hide the "delete post" button from users who are not Admin etc..

Thanks

Comment: you can use ng-show or ng-hide or ng-if  https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

Answer (score 0):

Mean.js stores user roles in user.roles array and it is available to you from Authentication service, which is included in default template for the controllers. 
In controller you can do:

```
   $scope.authentication = Authentication;
```

And you can use it like

```
 <button  ng-if="authentication.user.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1" type="button">
   Delete
 </button>
```

in your view to show anything specific to admin users in mean.js. This will hide this button from the users other than admin.